# Possíveis valores para ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey?

Tags: c#, wpf

Recentemente tive um `bug` com `combobox` no `WPF`. Era um `bug` relacionado a um "embaçamento" na fonte quando tinha apenas um item no `combobox` enquanto esse abria. Resolvi o problema removendo a animação do mesmo com a solução abaixo.

Gostaria de saber quais outros valores possíveis posso definir além de `None`. Pesquisa na **MSDN** mas não achei nada.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}">
       None
  </PopupAnimation>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O elemento `PopupAnimation` usa a enumeração de mesmo nome, descrita [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popupanimation(v=vs.110).aspx). Possíveis valores são `None`, `Scroll`, `Fade` e `Slide`.

Comment: Valeu! Não tinha achado essa página na MSDN!